# Jenkins pulling code from bitbucket and executing the pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, artifactory, jenkins-groovy

I have 3 pipelines- A, B, C.
A takes the backup of of my server.
B uploads the backup to artifactory
C schedules A by passing different parameters everyday by 4 AM

I want to move my code to bit bucket. Jenkins should pull the code from bitbucket and execute this pipeline everyday by 4 AM.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please select git option in job configuration and provide the repository path and the credentials.

Then, Please select build periodically in build triggers and provide the below time. It will execute the code everyday at 4 am.

```
H 04 * * *
```

Comment: It is not working for me. How can I do those configuration.

Comment: You have the pipeline job access configure access, in the left side you will find configure option , click it you will go inside job configuration page . 

Goto source code mangement tab-->click git radio button--> Provide the bitbucket repo URL--> add the credentials if not added --> select the branch for that build
**To enable the job to run everyday please follow**
Goto job --> Configure-->Build Triggers-->Build periodically--> Add the time given above.